# How to Perform a PipelineModel.transform inside an spark.sql query

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

I have a DataFrame "testData" with the columns:

```
"PRODUCT_LINE","PROFESSION","GENDER","MARITAL_STATUS"
```

with test data to perform some predictions. 
I have to predict the "PRODUCT_LINE" from the other attributes, for that, I created a ModelRandomForest that is a PipelineModel "modelrf_loaded".

Its stored and loaded, working fine, but now i want to do this dynamically in Spark SQL inside a query (maybe with an udf) this way:

```
val prediction3 = spark.sql("SELECT predictProductLine(*) FROM testData")
```

Besides being able to get the result I want with a different syntax like this:

```
def predictProductLine(dataframe:DataFrame):DataFrame = {
    modelrf_loaded.transform(dataframe) 
}
predictProductLine(spark.sql("SELECT * FROM testData")).show
```

I explicitly want the operation being performed in a single SQL query! Is there any solution for using Spark SQL this way?

**EDIT:**

I came up with some udf that maybe can be used like this:

```
def udfTest(GENDER:String,AGE:Integer,MARITAL_STATUS:String,PROFESSION:String):String = {
    //case class ObjData(GENDER:String,AGE:Integer,MARITAL_STATUS:String,PROFESSION:String)
    val vardata = Seq(ObjData(GENDER,AGE,MARITAL_STATUS,PROFESSION)).toDF()
    var modelrf_loaded = PipelineModel.load("ModelRandomForest")
    val prediction = modelrf_loaded.transform(vardata)
    (prediction.first.getString(11))
}

spark.udf.register("Predict",udfTest _)
val prediction = spark.sql("SELECT Predict(GENDER,AGE,MARITAL_STATUS,PROFESSION) FROM testData")
```

I'm not an expert in scala/spark so maybe there is another solution, but this is the only thing comming into my head.

In this solution exist 2 problems:

- I need to define the class **ObjData** outside the call, the class definition inside the udf raises a compilation error, so I can't use it in 1 line as I wanted
- It raises a NullPointerException when I try to do **prediction.show** although it compiles

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use ML models with SQL and they cannot be applied in udf, as transform method is `(Dataset) => Dataset`. You'll have to use standard `Dataset` API here.

Comment: Maybe I can use a udf to perform the change between different object types, then operate inside, then return a supported type with the prediction. I updated the question with an example. Thanks for your answer!